# Not a string after textscan in Matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I am reading a string of the form: `Text1_Text2_Text3_Text4`. I do a `textscan` with the delimiter `"_"`:

`myString = textscan('Text1_Text2_Text3_Text4', '%s', 'delimiter','_');`

output:

`'Text1'
'Text2'
'Text3'
'Text4'`

This is a char array. To transform it to a String I use `myString = myString{1}`.
I want to know the size of the second index -> `numel(myString(2));`
But MATLAB always returns 1. Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. It works if I do

`myString = myString{1}(2);
myString = myString{1};`

But I would need a lot of variables if I also want to know the size of index 1, 3 or 4 so there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the size of all strings:

```
>> sizes = cellfun(@numel, myString)

>> sizes =

     5
     5
     5
     5
```

To know the size of the `k`-th string only:

```
>> k = 2;
>> numel(myString{k})

>> ans =

     5
```

Comment: Almost. I would like to know the size of the second element only. Or to make it more clear, the size changes within the loop, so something like size(k) would be great. Thanks!